# best way to take element from XDocument and parse it to JSON with Json.net?

Tags: json, serialization, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

do I need to go through XmlDocument object in order to use JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode? I need only one composed elements from the source XDocument.

In short - what is the best way (also from performance perspective) to do so?